# selecting value based on sibling value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I've been trying to figure out a way without using a foreach loop to select the values of what I need from an xml.

Here is the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Count>116</Count>
<Message>Results returned successfully</Message>
<SearchCriteria>VIN:KM8JM12B66U253804</SearchCriteria>
<Results>
    <DecodedVariable>
        <VariableId>10</VariableId>
        <Variable>Destination Market</Variable>
    </DecodedVariable>
    <DecodedVariable>
        <VariableId>26</VariableId>
        <Variable>Make</Variable>
        <ValueId>498</ValueId>
        <Value>HYUNDAI</Value>
    </DecodedVariable>
    <DecodedVariable>
        <VariableId>27</VariableId>
        <Variable>Manufacturer Name</Variable>
        <ValueId>1034</ValueId>
        <Value>HYUNDAI-KIA AMERICA TECHNICAL CENTER INC (HATCI)</Value>
    </DecodedVariable>
    <DecodedVariable>
        <VariableId>28</VariableId>
        <Variable>Model</Variable>
        <ValueId>2058</ValueId>
        <Value>Tucson</Value>
    </DecodedVariable>
    <DecodedVariable>
        <VariableId>29</VariableId>
        <Variable>Model Year</Variable>
        <ValueId/>
        <Value>2006</Value>
    </DecodedVariable>
</Results>
```

Using linq using the second `DecodedVariable` node, how can I selected the value of `HYUNDAI` when the `variabileId = 26`?

Answer (score 1):

A real XML has only one root element. You have 'Response', 'Count', 'Message', 'SearchCriteria' and 'Results' as root elements. You also have to close the 'Response' tag.

Crate an structure that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Content>
    <Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Count>116</Count>
    ...
</Content>
```

You can then load your XML with `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse()` or `XDocument.Load()`.

The following is an example to get down to the value you're looking for.

```
//Load XML
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><Content><Count>116</Count><Message>Results returned successfully</Message><SearchCriteria>VIN:KM8JM12B66U253804</SearchCriteria><Results>    <DecodedVariable>        <VariableId>10</VariableId>        <Variable>Destination Market</Variable>    </DecodedVariable>    <DecodedVariable>        <VariableId>26</VariableId>        <Variable>Make</Variable>        <ValueId>498</ValueId>        <Value>HYUNDAI</Value>    </DecodedVariable>    <DecodedVariable>        <VariableId>27</VariableId>        <Variable>Manufacturer Name</Variable>        <ValueId>1034</ValueId>        <Value>HYUNDAI-KIA AMERICA TECHNICAL CENTER INC (HATCI)</Value>    </DecodedVariable>    <DecodedVariable>        <VariableId>28</VariableId>        <Variable>Model</Variable>        <ValueId>2058</ValueId>        <Value>Tucson</Value>    </DecodedVariable>    <DecodedVariable>        <VariableId>29</VariableId>        <Variable>Model Year</Variable>        <ValueId/>        <Value>2006</Value>    </DecodedVariable></Results></Content>");
//Select root Element
var root = document?.Root;
//Go down to the 'Results' element. There is just a single element so use 'Element()'
var results = root?.Element("Results");
//Get every 'DecodedVariable'. There are multiple elements so use 'Elements()'
var decodedVariables = results?.Elements("DecodedVariable");
//Select the only element with 'VariableId'==26 or null if no element maches
var value = decodedVariables?.SingleOrDefault((decodedVariable) =>
//Do the following for every element 'DecodedVariable'
{
    //Try parse the 'VariableId' as int
    if (int.TryParse(decodedVariable?.Element("VariableId")?.Value, out int id))
        //Compare the value of 'VariableId' with the value you're looking for. In this case 26
        if (id == 26)
            //This is the correct 'DecodedVariable' element
            return true;
    //This is not the correct 'DecodedVariable' element
    return false;
})
//Get the element 'Value' from the element 'DecodedVariable' then get the value from the element 'Value'
?.Element("Value")?.Value;

//'HYUNDAI' is stored in 'value'
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Expect null everywhere. `XElement.Elements()` just returns null if it can't find a matching element. That's why I used `?.`. You may not need it if you validate against a schema beforehand. Though you don't do this or you would have realised that your xml is not valid.

You don't have to parse the 'VariableId' to int. You could also compare it as a string with `== 26.ToString()`.

I'm sure I forgot to check for null in a few places. So check the code yourself before using it.